# Is there a skin for VLC that would allow the same access and options as the native style?

Tags: vlc, video-player

I mean a skin that would just improve appearance but without removing the options of the native style, like the main toolbar and the playlist options (access to my music folder, freebox tv list and the like)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the only skins out there that allow this are the ones that doesn't put the 'skin' on the playlist and leave it as it is. All playlists that follow the skin lose their advanced features.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the skin site?  Darklounge sounds somewhat like what you want, but I'm not sure. if it was the buttons or the menu's your after.

[VLC Skins](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/skins.php?sort=rating)

Comment: Darklounge is no good - and from what i know the rest from the vlc site are at best no better. I heard that there might be others.

Comment: I'm sure there are.  I'm taking it you mean menus and no buttons?

Comment: yes, i mean, accessibility to features as in the image above -- that i cannot see in Darklounge, for example --